# awk quote fields containing non-numeric characters

Tags: awk, pattern-matching

I would like to put quotes around the fields in a delimited file that have non-numeric characters in a file as well as remove any internal double quotes in the field.

For example:

```
 0.010|hel"l&0|w#rld'|201
 0.301|s@yin%"|t^h!at|5.0
```

Should result in:

```
 0.010|"hell&0"|"w#rld'"|201
 0.301|"s@yin%"|"t^h!at"|5.0
```

Comment: The way to quote internal quotes in a CSV field is to double them: `hel"l&0` ==> `"hel""l&0"` (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4180.txt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ cat del.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }

{
  for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {
    if ($i ~ /[^0-9.]/) {
      gsub("\"","", $i)
      $i = "\"" $i "\""
    }
  }
  print
}

$ awk -f del.awk file.txt
0.010|"hell&0"|"w#rld'"|201
0.301|"s@yin%"|"t^h!at"|5.0
```

**EDIT**:

As pointed out in the comments, a more robust solution might be to instead check if the field can be converted to a number and surrounded with quotes only if not:

```
BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }

{
  for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) {        
    if ($i != $i + 0) {
      # the field could not be converted into a number
      gsub("\"","", $i);
      $i = "\"" $i "\""
    }
  }
  print
}
```

Note that in the first solution `0x0A` would be surrounded by quotes while in the second solution it will not. Conversely, in the first solution `0.3.1` would *not* be surrounded with quotes, but in the second solution it will be.

It may not matter, depending on your data, but there's a fair chance that the second solution is more suitable.

Comment: You could also write `if ($i != $i + 0)` to distinguish between numbers and non-numbers.

Comment: Thanks, @glennjackman, I like that idea a lot. I've updated the answer suggesting it as likely a more robust alternative.